# Mysql combine count query into single column from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'Details' as below

```
| ID | NAME   | PARTS | SERVICE | LOCATION | TIME          |
|----|--------|-------|---------|----------|---------------|
| 1  | John   | 5     | Repair  | A        | 1597893635294 |
| 2  | Smith  | 1     | Install | A        | 1597893635294 |
| 3  | Will   | 1     | Repair  | B        | 1597893635294 |
| 4  | Jade   | 10    | Install | A        | 1597893635294 |
| 5  | George | 2     | Install | B        | 1597893635294 |
| 6  | Ray    | 4     | Repair  | A        | 1597893635294 |
```

I need the total number of rows sorted based service and location

`Select SERVICE,LOCATION,count(*) as TOTAL from Details group by SERVICE,LOCATION order by SERVICE desc;`

which gives result as

```
| SERVICE | LOCATION | TOTAL |
|---------|----------|-------|
| Repair  | A        | 2     |
| Repair  | B        | 1     |
| Install | A        | 2     |
| Install | B        | 1     |
```

I need result as

```
| SERVICE | A | B | TOTAL |
|---------|---|---|-------|
| Repair  | 2 | 1 | 3     |
| Install | 2 | 1 | 3     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below using `conditional aggregation`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2849ab9de51bb29698822e104136750)**

```
Select SERVICE,
       count(case when location='A' then 1 end) as A,
       count(case when location='B' then 1 end) as B,
       count(*) as TOTAL 
from Details group by SERVICE
order by SERVICE desc
```

Comment: What is 'total' in case expression, Table Details doesn't have a column as total ?

Comment: @HariPrasandh, check now

Comment: Query is executed, 
Total is fetched correctly but case expression is not working as intended, it just places '1' instead of actual count

Comment: @HariPrasandh, check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2849ab9de51bb29698822e104136750

Comment: Works.  I missed changing max() to count() in select, when the query was changed